# IOS Screen Size Requirements

Tags: ios, screen

I have an iphone app nearing completion that does not support 3.5 inch screens.

Do all apps have to support iphone/ipod versions 4 and below?  Do I need to modify my app?

To be more clear, I want to know whether my app is likely to be rejected if it does not support 3.5 inch displays.

Comment: What do mean by my choice?  Will the appstore accept it?

Comment: why not? its your choice

Comment: Is there an appstore requirement that 3.5 inch screens be supported?

Comment: I think this question is more of the "Opinion Based" type .. :(

Comment: In actual answer to your question there is absolutely no requirement from the app store. They won't reject your app.  If it looks crap on ancient devices - that's just your choice.  (95% of Apps look crap.) Food for thought: 3.5 inch owners are useless income generators.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should modify your app to support it.
Cause iPhone4 or iPhone4S still popular.

I think your app running iOS 7, so support 3.5 inch is easy to use Auto Layout.

[Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I dont use interface builder; I do everything programatically and I use sprite graphics; I'll have to scale them; also, the memory requirements may not be adequately met with iphone 4 and below (I have a HUGE cocos2d fully animated roguelike) since I had switched to iphone 5 as a target instead of 4 mainly because of memory issues and slow performance.

Comment: Auto Layout can also use code programatically. I know what you meaning. The App Store Review Guidelines not mention app must support 3.5 inch.

Comment: That's really what I wanted to know, because I know in the past, lack of 3.5 inch support meant rejection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support your app based on device model/screen size, I'm afraid this is *NOT possible* as of today (iOS 7). However, you can limit your devices based on the hardware capabilities - `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key of app's `Info.plist`.

Checkout [this](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/30/uirequireddevicecapabilities-and-device-compatibility-matrix) link for device and capabilities matrix.